# Google Charts Category Filter using SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a dropdown filter that will allow filtering of chart(s). My webmethod is working (I've tested it using a chart) but my ajax is not returning any rows within the dropdown.

Any help really appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCountryChart);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDivisionChart);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('Dashboard'));

    function drawCountryChart() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Season.aspx/GetCountry",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var CountryData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                    'containerId': 'ddlCountry',
                    'options': {
                        'filterColumnLabel': 'CountryName',
                        'ui': {
                            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                            'allowTyping': false,
                            'allowMultiple': false
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to draw the filter on its own,
need to assign the data table property and call the `draw` method...

```
var CountryData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'ddlCountry',
    'dataTable': CountryData,  // <-- assign data table
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'CountryName',
        'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': false
        }
    }
});
namePicker.draw();  // <-- draw control
```

---

**note**: recommend *not* using the older chart library --> `jsapi`
according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will only affect the `load` and `callback` statements,
in fact, the `callback` can be added to the `load` statement directly...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawCountryChart();
    drawDivisionChart();
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

Comment: also need to load the `'controls'` package when using `ChartWrapper` or `ControlWrapper`, see `load` statement above...

Comment: Thanks White Hat. Fingers crossed those changes will fix it